# How to import bookmarks into Edge browser in Windows 10

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, bookmarks, microsoft-edge

I have just witnessed two non-techy users' first time in Windows 10.

The first thing both of them said when opening the new Edge browser for the first time was "Where are my favourites (favorites for you US people)?". and "How do I get my favourites back?".

- Thought one: "Why had it not imported bookmarks from IE?"
- Thought two: "Easy"

I found the "Hub" menu and the favourites / bookmarks inside it ... but I could not find a way to import from IE.

... answer below on how to import bookmarks in windows 10!

Answer (score 3):

#### Method one

Follow method stated on [Get started with Windows 10 on Microsoft.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/getstarted-get-to-know-microsoft-edge):

[image: Import Favourites]

- Enter "Hub" menu on top right - the three horizontal lines that looks a bit like a burger menu with the lettuce hanging out.
- Click the "Import favourites" blue text on top right *which my mind could not see as it faded into the background as visual noise*.
- Select "Internet Explorer" and click the Import button.

#### Method two

[image: Using settings]

- Click menu (ellipsis ... menu top right)
- Settings
- use the "Import favourites from another browser" link

Comment: My previous search involved copying files and deleting registry keys. I did that and it worked, but I also afterwards found this way. Much easier and it works too.

Comment: Note that Edge does not currently support bookmarklets ... you may need to install an extension like TamperMonkey